# Mac Os - Vagrant: Cannot install plugins

Tags: macos, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I have a problem with Vagrant running on my Mac.

**Problem:**

Whenever I type in

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
```

I get the following error:

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tmpdir.rb:92:in `ensure in mktmpdir': parent directory is world writable but not sticky (ArgumentError)
```

**What I already tried**

... and which didn't help yet:

```
sudo vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf

sudo true && vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
```

Because some other threadsd assume that this might be caused by "bundler" I also tried:

```
rm -rf cd /Users/myunsername/.bundle/cache
```

As I mentioned, it didn't help yet, so if anyone had this problem before, I would appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.  Try https://apple.stackexchange.com